# Vb.net form controls gets slower on clearing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Given the option, i need to reuse this form N times as I might need to fill the controls times many items I have to, the sub does what it is intended to do but after I added say 5 items it starts getting slower and slower everytime it excutes to the point that is just unusable.. any ideas on what is happening or any other method to achieve so whitout slowing down the process?

```
sub clear_form (sender, e)
    Me.Controls.Clear() 'removes all the controls on the form
    dish = Nothing 'my model
    dishes = Nothing ' array of model
    Me.InitializeComponent() 'load all the controls again
    set.controls() 'initial desired state of the controls
    form_Load(sender, e)
 end sub
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove all the controls just to 'set the initial state'?  Controls are complex objects and needlessly creating and recreating them (likely without disposing of them) is costly.  You could more easily and efficiently  create and show a new form instance

Comment: easier for me to go back to the initial state.. there is a whole lot of controls in that form.. the thing is why it does works fine the first several times and after that, starts slowing down.. i mean i have 32gb ram ddr4 with an intel core i7 7700k and a samsun evo ssd .. i think that such small task could not hit this way this kind of hardware..

Comment: Check in task manager - your app is almost certainly leaking.  It may be easier but it is costly.  As I said it would be simpler to just show a new form instance.  Throwing out the controls to clear the form is like buying new dishes everytime you eat

Comment: Will do and comment back

Comment: yes it is leaking.. the memory starts to add up and up with every item.. so what should I do..

Comment: Just because you think it is a 'simple task' doesnt mean it is. As I have said twice now, create a show a new form instance if you dont want to write a method to reset the controls manually

Comment: Ok so I guess thats gonna be the way , thanks